# Can my requirements be met with JMX?

Tags: weblogic, jmx

I am completely new to [JMX](http://java.sun.com/javase/technologies/core/mntr-mgmt/javamanagement/). I have a specific requirement and wanted to know if it is possible to accomplish within the scope of JMX.

#### Requirements:

I have a set of resources which include many weblogic instances, [jBoss](http://www.jboss.org/) instances and [Tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org/) instances running across many servers. Now I need a one stop solution, UI to monitor these resources, check their current status and if they are down, I need to start and stop them from that webpage.

Is this possible using JMX?

Answer (score 2):

You could use [nagios](http://www.nagios.org) combined with [check_jmx](http://www.nagiosexchange.org/cgi-bin/page.cgi?g=2338.html;d=1) to monitor ([create statistics](http://www.pnp4nagios.org/))
and may trigger a restart of a resource. (I'm not sure if can trigger a restart direct via JMX)

Answer (score 0):

Check out Jopr, http://www.jboss.org/jopr/

Comment: Actually rather have a look at RHQ - which includes all former Jopr bits, but which is more up to date. http://rhq-project.org/

Answer (score 0):

[jmx4perl](http://www.jmx4perl.org) comes with a full featured Nagios Plugin [check_jmx4perl](http://search.cpan.org/~roland/jmx4perl/scripts/check_jmx4perl) for access JMX information. It comes with a set of preconfigured check for various resources, currently for JBoss, Tomcat and Jetty (more are in the pipeline).